# Jquery FadeIn/FadeOut too abrupt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

I have this js code,

EDIT: Forgot to mention, i have this fadeIn when the iframe loads

```
$('iframe').on('load', function(){
muteVideo();
playVideo();
$(this).fadeIn();
$('.ligarsom').fadeIn();
setTimeout(function() {$('.ligarsom').fadeOut()}, 20000);
});
```

and this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ligarsom').on('click', function(){
$('.ligarsom').fadeOut(1000);
});
}); 
</script>
```

and this html

```
<div class="ligarsom" style="display:none;"></div>
```

When i use style="visibility:hidden" the div doesn't even appear. And like above fadeOut doesn't work as it should, there is no animation, it just hides abruptaly. Is there anything wrong in my code?

See it in action in: www.finecolor.com.br/novo

Comment: how can you click a hidden div?

Comment: your div is already hidden .... no logic in your code

Comment: ...also you're not closing your $(document).ready ... your close brace and parenthesis (`});`) are only on the .on event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:** `transition:` is conflicting with `fadOut()` Function animation.

**Solution:** Add this to your css:

```
.ligarsom, .ligarsom:hover{
    transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in this way

HTML

```
<div class="ligarsom">click here</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ligarsom").click(function() {

    $(this).fadeOut(100);

});
```

});

Comment: I agree that this is a valuable edit to his code. I don't believe it answers his specific problem though.